# How to call every struct method inside write transaction

Tags: swift, realm, closures

I created struct `Repository` for manipulating with objects of Realm database (changing some properties, adding new objects, deleting, etc.). When I want to write to the database, I have to do it inside do-try-catch block, so I created a method with completion which I call every time I need to write something to the database

```
private func action(_ completion: () -> Void) {
    do {
        try realm.write {
            completion()
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

then I call methods for manipulating with objects like this:

```
func createObject(_ object: MyObject) {
    action {
        realm.add(object)
    }
}

func deleteObject(_ object: MyObject) {
    action {
        realm.delete(object)
    }
}

func setTitleForObject(_ object: MyObject, title: String) {
    action {
        object.title = title
    }
}

...
```

My question is, is there any way how I can call every method inside this `Repository` struct inside write transaction in do-try-catch block by default instead of calling it inside completion of `action`? (or is some better way how to write to the Realm database without do-try-catch block?)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, there is no way to write data to realm without write transaction and without `try-catch`.

`realm.write()` is a convenient wrapper of transaction building with `beginWrite()` and `commitWrite()` calls.
These two functions build a transaction and `commitWrite()` is throwable, so you need to wrap to `try-catch`, anyway.

See https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#writes

Example of using `beginWrite()+commitWrite()`  https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#interface-driven-writes

There are a lot of failures could happen during write transactions. So, simply, it is not safe to not to handle it somehow.

Also grouping write transactions by "action" is not a good idea if you going to process big amounts of objects because write transactions are **costly**. You'd rather group these changes to a single transaction instead of having a lot of small transactions.

Comment: I am not grouping write transactions. It’s single transaction. I just wrote `action` method for saving me many lines of code

Comment: Single transaction is one that placed into write closure. On every `action()` call you create a separate transaction.